# How many ordered $2$ tuples can be chosen from $(1,2,..n)$ such that their sum is a perfect square?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ordered $2$ tuples can be chosen from $(1,2,..n)$ such that the sum of the two numbers within the tuple is a perfect square?

Will generating functions help here?

Comment: You can arrange the ordered 2-tuples into a square array.  The 2-tuples with constant sum appear along diagonals.  So for squares in $[0,n]$ the sequence of counts of 2-tuples increases, then for squares in $[n,2n]$, the sequence of counts of 2-tuples decreases.  Is there something about this that is blocking your progress?

Comment: The set of triangular numbers has the property that $T_{n-1} + T_{n}=n^2$. that is two consecutive triangular numbers sum up to a perfect square.